# What is the difference between "shooting" and "safety" glasses?

Tags: sunglasses

The local shooting range requires eye protection, when I look on Amazon there are "shooting glasses" in the hunting section, and then there are "safety glasses" in other sections.

From what I can tell, there isn't much of a difference between the two, they both protect from UV and are made from plastic, is there an actual difference (besides marketing) between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Safety glasses** would presumably meet some [safety standard](https://blog.safetyglassesusa.com/what-does-ansi-z87-1-2010-certified-mean/), for example impact resistance, and the standard so meet would be cited.

**Shooting glasses** might offer some impact resistance (or other protection...), but wouldn't have to meet the standard.

Comment: But shooting glasses will also say that they meet ANSI Z87.1 standards

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh - The point is that there is no ANSI or legal standard for "shooting glasses." I could legally label any pair of sun glasses as "shooting glasses" (without specifying that they meet ANSI Z87.1). // edited answer to indicate that "safety glasses" should indicate what safety standard they meet.

Comment: That makes more sense